# Recursively select all child DIV elements only in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement where I need to set a repeating CSS to all div blocks inside a parent div. Is it possible to select all DIV elements only using CSS?

**Example**

```
<div id="root">
    <div class="App">
        <div class="layout">
            <div>...</div>
            <div>...</div>
            <div>
                <div>...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="something-else">...</div>
```

Now, I need to set some CSS to all the DIVs that are inside `#root` only.

Comment: Is question answered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#root div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Ah! Gosh..that was silly..I have been doing this over and over again and didnt check that my hot-reload wasnt running.